# BeanUtils DateConverter Ignored

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a case where I need to convert from a Date field in one object to a String in another field, in a given format. So, I tried this bit of code:

```
    DateConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter();
    dateConverter.setPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    ConvertUtils.register(dateConverter, Date.class);
```

The setter method will look something like this:

```
public setDateOfBirth(Record record, Date dob) throws Exception {
    BeanUtils.copyProperty(record, "dateOfBirth", dob);
}
```

Unfortunately, the DateConverter seems to be ignored entirely. The target object is populated, but apparently only by using the "toString()" representation of the date object.

The resulting String is being sent to a web service and MUST be in the correct format. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you use your own converter, you should use BeanUtilsBean instance and ConvertUtilsBean instance, instead of the static methods on BeanUtils and ConvertUtils.

[Here is a demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/ConvertUtilsDemo.htm)